# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByID

Tags: javascript, sdk

I'm very new to Javascript.

I have these codes to display out simple events and timings. But when I run my Samsung Smart TV emulator, this error keeps appearing. The First is the error, while the second are my codes
Error Detail:

> Uncaught TypeError:Object# has no method 'getElementByID'

These are my codes

```
This.enableKeys();

widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();
    var thelabels = new Array();
    thelabels[0] = "StartTime: 0.900am";
    document.getElementByID('footer').innterHTML = "StartTime: 10.00pm"
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('footer').innterHTML = thelabels[i];i++;        if(i > = thelabels.length) i=0;},5000);
```

Would truely greatly appreciate it if anyone has a solution for this. I'm new to java so I might not see the obvious error. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Never use "Java" as shorthand for "Javascript". These two languages have as much in common as Iced Tea and Long Island Iced Tea.

Comment: @Philipp that is, without a doubt, the best comparison I've ever heard :D

Comment: @Phil What about a java coffee and ice cubes?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about simple misspellings.

Answer (score 4):

javascript is case sensitive, you also misspelled innerHTML

```
document.getElementByID('footer').innterHTML = "StartTime: 10.00pm"
```

needs to be:

```
document.getElementById('footer').innerHTML = "StartTime: 10.00pm";
```

Comment: and yes, javascript is NOT java.

Comment: +1 You, my friend, are probably the only person who would be able to post an answer without ***THIS, IS NOT, JAVA!***